# How does the Buddha address powerful spiritual experiences in monks?

Tags: personal-experience

Specifically, loss of time, distance and size. Also advanced forms of empathy and being in two locations at once. I realise this is quite vague but I hesitate at giving details. I'm more concerned with how these are addressed in Buddhism.

Comment: Any particular reason this is tagged 'Triratna'? ie., are you looking for answers that come from members of this community?

Comment: Not really. Anyone with knowledge of Buddhism may answer. I couldn't find tags related to the question. Perhaps I'm not creative enough.

Comment: Are these experiences as a result of, or during, meditation?

Comment: ChrisW. They occur outside of meditation.

Comment: These kinds of experiences are commonplace but the practice is about transcending experience so in Buddhism they are not considered important. For an ultimate view there will be a loss of time, distance and size since these are not truly real phenomena, while empathy is bound to grow as we more closely approach a state or realisation of unity and shared identity. As for being in two places at once, Buddhism teaches that there are not two places. Extension would be conceptual. Maybe you're being afflicted by intuitions and visions of truth. Lucky you.

Comment: Thank you PeterJ. It's been very helpful to obtain knowledge from these experiences. As one example, I see anatta quite a lot in other things. A car going down the road isn't a car but an ephemeral cohesion of earths components travelling over itself. Isn't this what Buddha did with his insights and experiences? Didn't he learn from them and then develop a refined knowing about reality? Aren't they important in that sense?

Comment: PeterJ - I did find a sutra in which Sharuputra and another monk conversed about this very thing. I think the experiences are called siddhi. The other monk was able to travel vast distances across the universe and Shariputra bestowed his assertion upon him to realise reality from the confines of his body. I've forgotten what the sutra is called. Perhaps someone here can inform?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what type of answer you are looking for (sutra references about supernormal powers??), but I'll just paraphrase what I heard recently from a Theravada monk that seemed like extremely good advice which reportedly came from [Ajahn Chah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajahn_Chah)...

The advice was to simply be mindful and beware growing attached to any weird experiences you have while meditating. With the deep concentrations found in meditation you can have all kinds of seemingly supernatural experiences. So what. They are no more real or inherently existing (nor less!) than any thing experienced in waking life. If you have weird or seemingly supernatural experiences in waking life... again, so what. They are no more real (nor less!) than what you might experience in a dream. All things lack inherent existence and are not worthy of grasping. Grasp at them and you will incur suffering for yourself and others. So don't do it! :)

Now, the one thing you said that I think might deserve extra attention is your remark about "advanced forms of empathy." If by "empathy" you mean compassion (the wish for others to be free from suffering), then this is an unalloyed virtue that should be cultivated to perfection. To do so, I'd suggest [Shantideva's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UHMSY8) and loving kindness or bodhicitta meditation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. From what you say, I see that they can become hindrances then. Whilst they are interesting they come and go. I figure that this is something the Buddha would say about them.

Comment: Yes, I think they can become hindrances if you get attached to them or develop arrogance because of them. However, I have not had these experiences so what do I know :) If you don't mind me asking... have you taken Bodhisattva vows? Please feel free to not answer if you don't wish of course!

Comment: No, I don't know what the Bodhisattva vows are.

Comment: The main vow is to generate the mind of enlightenment for the sole purpose of helping all sentient beings. ie., the supreme and completely perfect altruistic motivation.

Comment: I see. If you have a resource for the Bodhisattva vow, I'd be interested in taking a look. Thank you for your answers. :-)

Comment: I can't think of any better resource than Shantideva's Guide linked in the above answer ;)

Comment: You are very welcome. And along with reading Shantideva's Masterpiece you can follow along as HHDL explains it: https://www.amazon.com/Benefit-All-Beings-Commentary-Bodhisattva-ebook/dp/B01C64RSHK/ref=pd_sbs_351_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01C64RSHK&pd_rd_r=5b3e9384-b77e-11e8-a6e4-7ffe77228f05&pd_rd_w=csvi1&pd_rd_wg=j6crP&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=1646818405999967777&pf_rd_r=HP53KXTHX7R3D18E9CF6&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&psc=1&refRID=HP53KXTHX7R3D18E9CF6